# Why is my python multiprocess program running only in one core?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to make a multi-process class objects run in all cpu cores in my python program. The code works, but it only runs in one core.

I wonder if the child processes are running sequentially, but I cant't find an easy way to test this or to avoid it.

My code looks something like this

```py
#child processes

import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
class child(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self,comm):
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.comm = comm
    def run(self):
        self.score = self.doWork()
        self.comm.put([self.score])
    def doWork(self):
        k = 0
        for x in range(9999):
            for y in range(9999):
                k = k + 1
        return random.randint(1,1000)
#main process
def runSubProcess():
     list = []
     queue = mp.Queue()
     for p in range(4):
         p = child(queue)
         p.start()
         p.join()
         list.append(p)
     stillRunning = True
     while stillRunning:
         stillRunning = False
         for p in list:
             if p.is_alive():
                 stillRunning = True
         time.sleep(0.1)
     while not queue.empty():
         item = queue.get()
         print (item)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    runSubProcess()
```

I'm running python 3.8 64 bits in a 4-core environment using Windows 10

Version string:

Python 3.8.0a1 (tags/v3.8.0a1:e75eeb00b5, Feb  3 2019, 19:46:54) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Answer (score 4):

Because you immediately `join()` it after starting. That makes the main program wait for the child to finish.

Start all of them first, then join all of them in another loop, like this:

```
def runSubProcess():
     list = []
     queue = mp.Queue()
     for p in range(4):
         p = child(queue)
         p.start()
         list.append(p)
     for p in list:
         p.join()
     while not queue.empty():
         item = queue.get()
         print (item)
```

Note that there's no need for sleeping, since `join()` will "sleep" by itself, if needed - even better: without using any CPU.